# String to start with number, then dots and commas in Java

Tags: java, android, regex, numbers

Friends, I have the following problem - I have a string in Java, that contains characters, digits, dots, commas and etc. Here is an example of what I need to do:

I have the following string:

```
"Value:, £ 13.110,12"
```

Now, I want the new string to start with a number, then it can have other numbers, dots and commas. Something like that:

"13.110,12"

I am trying to do that like this, but with no success:

```
valueLabel.replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+", "");
```

But it gives me this:

```
",13.110,12"
```

I have an extra comma in the beginning, which I want to remove. How to change the regex to do that?

Comment: the format of your strings is always the same?

Comment: Yes, it is always the same, only the number may be different.

Comment: In what format receives this number ? What will be the input I mean.

Comment: If the format is the same, why not just use `substring`?

Comment: Will there be only 2 numbers with different values?

Comment: Try `valueLabel = valueLabel.replaceAll("Value:, £ ", "");`

Answer (score 2):

using replace function,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String valueLabel = "Value:, £ 13.110,12";
        String res = valueLabel.replaceAll("Value:, £ ", "");
        System.out.println(res);
    }
```

**Output**

```
13.110,12
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try this :

```
"^[^0-9.]+"
```

it will check only the begginning of the string and stop when firt number will be find so `Value:, £` will be removed.

but if you can have this :

```
"Value:1, £ 12.121,5"
```

result will be `, £ 12.121,5`

but if you are sure to don't have any number before the number start, it will be ok ;)

Comment: +1. the anchor is the key, but I would leave the dot out as well: `"^[^0-9]+"`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    String nm="Value:, £ 13.110,12";
    String arr[]=nm.split(" ");
    Log.e("arr",arr[2]);
```

arr[2] will be your final string which you want